# How to get the title of the current tab in firefox web extension?

Tags: javascript, json, tabs, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to code a simple firefox extension that displays the title of the current tab the user is viewing when the extension's button is pressed.

Here is my manifest.json file:

```
{

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Perspective",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "Displays current tab title when clicked",

    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ],

    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/border-48.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "browser_style": true,
        "default_popup": "popup/choose_page.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icons/news-icon-16.png",
            "32": "icons/news-icon-32.png"
        }
    }
}
```

And, here is my choose_page.js file

```
//Fetch the title of the active tab
console.log("-----------Button Clicked------------");
var activeTab = browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
console.log("---------Printing type of variable \"activeTab\"");
if (typeof activeTab == "undefined")
    console.log("The object is undefined")
else 
    console.log("The type of activeTab is:" + typeof activeTab)

console.log("The title of activeTab is:")
console.log(activeTab.title);
```

Whenever I click my extension's button, I get the following output in the console:

> -----------Button Clicked------------
>
> ---------Printing type of variable "activeTab"
>
> The type of activeTab is:object
>
> The title of activeTab is:
>
> undefined

Why is the title of "activeTab" undefined, and how do I actually get the title of the current tab the user is viewing?

Here is the link to all of the files in the extension: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L7vho9iSL9nX2LKBmCveJvODmKQBlqX9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query

> This is an asynchronous function that returns a Promise.

You have to wait for the promise's resolution first. Try something like this instead:

```
browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true})
  .then(tabs => {
    for (const tab of tabs) {
      console.log(tab.title);
    }
  });
```

Your `activeTab` variable is not the active tab, but a promise that you need to wait for the resolution for. Also, when the promise resolves, it gives you an *array* of tabs, not a single tab.

Comment: This worked. Could you also answer an additional question. What does `tabs =>` mean in your response? I read through some documentation on Promises, but I still don't understand its meaning.

Comment: That's an arrow function, it's shorthand for writing out "function" (among other things). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: So, just to clarify, writing tabs => is equivalent to writing function(tabs) where tabs is the object returned by browser.tabs.query()

Comment: No, `browser.tabs.query()` doesn't return anything - you have to pass it a function as an *argument*. (but in defining a function, you can either use `function functionName (args) { /* function block */` or `args => { /* function block */`.